# Referencing procedures in class files

Tags: vba

I have a Word VBA application that processes various documents to give them a consistent look (they are exported from another SW tool).  Each document type has a class file that "knows" how to make the conversion.  If a new document type is added, I create a new class file and then have to update several procedures to add a reference to the new class.  I'd like to automate the process of discovering and using the class files (they all follow a naming convention).  Here is what I have to collect references to the files:

```
Dim olVBCodeMod As VBComponents
Dim olaClasses() As VBComponent
Dim olVBCodeCmpt As VBComponent

Const slCLASS_NAME_PREFIX = "clsXXXX"

Set olVBCodeMod = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Collection.Item("Normal").VBComponents

ReDim olaClasses(0)
For Each olVBCodeCmpt In olVBCodeMod

    If olVBCodeCmpt.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule Then

        If InStr(olVBCodeCmpt.Name, slCLASS_NAME_PREFIX) = 1l Then

            Set olaClasses(UBound(olaClasses)) = olVBCodeCmpt
            ReDim Preserve olaClasses(UBound(otaClasses) + 1)
        End If
    End If

Next
ReDim Preserve olaClasses(UBound(otaClasses) - 1)
```

Unfortunately I'm not seeing any way to go from a reference to the class file to being able to run procedures in the class file, i.e. olaClasses(0).function1?

My fallback approach will be to create a sub that returns an object array (passed in as a parameter) with references to each class:

```
Set olaClasses(0) = New clsXXXX
```

This works, e.g. olaClasses(0).function1 gives me the correct response but it would be neat to be able to auto-discover the class files...

Comment: I'm not clear on what your "auto-discover" scenario would look like. Your "fallback" sentence makes no sense programatically. Like you have, the `New` keyword has to be part of the solution if you want to call a class method.

Comment: Auto-discover would collect the appropriate class files (based on their names) from the project it is run in.  Then for each class file, I'd be able to call the procedures that operate on the documents (one of which is, "is this my document") from the collection.  This way, if I have a new document format come along, I only need add a new class file and everything else works without any other changes.  For the fallback scenario, New is used, the references are collected in an array which will just grow as new classes are added. Then I iterate over the contents of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment, I think I'm with you now. So you want something like this:

```
Public Sub FormatActiveDocument()
    Dim className as String
    className = "cls" & [ActiveDocumentDocType or whatever] 
    Dim docClass as Object
    Set docClass = GetClass(className)
    If (obj is Nothing) Then MsgBox("ERROR: Missing VBA class '" & className & "'.")

    docClass.FormatDocument   '<-- MAGIC HAPPENS HERE (via late binding)
End Sub

Private Function GetClass(className as String) as Object    
    Dim classes() as VBComponent
    Set classes = ' [YOUR CODE]     
    For each obj as VBComponent In classes
        If (obj.Name = className) Then
            GetClass = obj
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    GetClass = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately this ends up where I did, with a reference of type vbext_ct_ClassModule, i.e. docClass.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule; it doesn't have access to the procedures in the file.  I had to make a couple of changes to your code: `If (obj is Nothing)` to `If (docClass is Nothing)` and `For each obj as VBComponent In classes` to `For Each obj In otaClasses` (obj has to be a Variant when working with arrays in VBA).  I replaced the array with a collection so obj could be a VBComponent, same result.